# convert detailed table row to column linq to sql lambda expression (master detail relationship)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Suppose we have a master-detail  relationship as follows

```
**Order Table**
   OrderId
   OrderDate

**OrderItem Table**
   OrderItemId
   OrderId 
   ItemId1
   Price1
   ItemId2
   Price2
   ItemId3
   Price3


**Item Table**
    ItemId
    ItemName
```

Each order can have a maximum of 3 order items. Hence, the OrderItem Table is designed as above. How can I write a LINQ to SQL lambda expression that gives the following output?

```
OrderId -- OrderDate -- Item1Name -- Item1Price -- Item2Name -- Item2Price -- Item3Name -- Item3Price
 1          8/27/2020    Item1        30            Item2        40
 2          8/27/2020    Item1        20            Item5        15            Item8        40
 3          8/27/2020    Item4        30
```

Comment: Can you provide the entity/class structure for the tables?

Comment: Linq to sql is used.

Comment: I understand that, but how is the class structure, does `OrderTable` class has the Collection of `OrderItemTable` and does `OrderIemTable` has reference to `OrderTable`?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty You don't have collections when using LINQ to SQL, just separate tables and joins. You are thinking of Entity Framework.

Comment: What values are in the `ItemId` fields when there is no item? Can you show the class definitions? What have you tried?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty
This is the structure of the tables in the database.

Comment: @NetMage
When the fields have no value, they are NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is not the best, it can be improved if we know more information what kind of technology are you using (.NET or .NETCore) so please answer the questions above and we can help you more. Currently this is the best that I can do for you:

```
var resultSet = (from orderItem in dataContext.OrderItem
                join order in dataContext.Order on orderItem.OrderId equals order.OrderId
                let firstItem = (from item in dataContext.Item
                                 where item.ItemId == orderItem.ItemId1
                                 select item).FirstOrDefault()
                let secondItem = (from item in dataContext.Item
                                 where item.ItemId == orderItem.ItemId2
                                 select item).FirstOrDefault()
                let thirdItem = (from item in dataContext.Item
                                 where item.ItemId == orderItem.ItemId3
                                 select item).FirstOrDefault()
                let firstItemExists = firstItem != null
                let secondItemExists = secondItem != null
                let thirdItemExists = thirdItem != null
                select new 
                {
                    OrderId = order.OrderId
                    OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
                    Item1Name = firstItemExists
                                ? firstItem.ItemName
                                : string.Empty
                    Item1Price = firstItemExists
                                ? firstItem.ItemPrice
                                : null
                    Item2Name = secondItemExists
                                ? secondItem.ItemName
                                : string.Empty
                    Item2Price = secondItemExists
                                ? secondItem.ItemPrice
                                : null
                    Item3Name = thirdItemExists
                                ? thirdItem.ItemName
                                : string.Empty
                    Item3Price = thirdItemExists
                                ? thirdItem.ItemPrice
                                : null
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what you want, but I did not test if LINQ to SQL can translate it:

```
var ans = (from o in Orders
           join oi in OrderItems on o.OrderId equals oi.OrderId
           join i1 in Items on oi.ItemId1 equals i1.ItemId into i1j
           from i1 in i1j.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join i2 in Items on oi.ItemId2 equals i2.ItemId into i2j
           from i2 in i2j.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join i3 in Items on oi.ItemId3 equals i3.ItemId into i3j
           from i3 in i3j.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new {
               o.OrderDate,
               Item1Name = i1.ItemName,
               Item1Price = oi.Price1,
               Item2Name = i2.ItemName,
               Item2Price = oi.Price2,
               Item3Name = i3.ItemName,
               Item3Price = oi.Price3,
           })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: For the left outer join (DefaultIfEmpty) syntax, I prefer something like:
`from o in Orders
join oi in OrderItems on .o.OrderId equals oi.OrderId
from i1 in Items.Where(item1 => oi.ItemId1 == item1.ItemId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from i2 in Items.Where(item2 => oi.ItemId2 == item2.ItemId).DefaultIfEmpty()
/// etc`
This results in the same generated SQL, but feels much more readable than the `into tempVar from temp2 in tempVar.DefaultIfEmpty()` syntax.